# Confused over setting up Sub Domain / Alias as a forwarder to location on apache server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ubuntu, subdomain

I am a little confused over the correct method to redirect/forward a domain alias (sub domain) to a directory on my website using apache.

I want the following domains http://helpdesk.xxxx.com and https://helpdesk.xxxx.com to redirect to https://www.xxxx.com/helpdesk.

I don't have a wildcard SSL cert so I am not sure if using rewrite would be the best method, I just want the server to forward any requests to those Alias on ports 443/80 to correct patch on the server.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can have this rule in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(helpdesk)\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%2/%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: but how will this work with https:// will the it redirect before the user is told the certificate is not trusted?

Comment: Cert negotiation always happens before `mod_rewrite` is even invoked.

Comment: so is there anyway to forward before cert negotiation?

Comment: You must do redirect rule inside Javascript to redirect before cert negotiation otherwise any webserver won't allow rewrite rules before cert negotiation due to security reasons.